# How much memory this array will take in C# when we pass it to function as parameter

Tags: c#

I am using an array in C# like so:

```
class abc 
{
    xyz x = new xyz(); // some other class
    public double [] arr = new double [100]; // Allocated 400 bytes 
                                             // for this array.
                                             // 100 is imaginary size 
                                             // shown here for simplicity.
                                             // Actual size will depend on input.
    private void something() 
    {
        x.funA(arr);
    }
}
```

In class `abc` above array is consuming 400 bytes. Now, I have passed this array in some function as a parameter which is in class `xyz`.

My question is whether new 400 bytes will be allocated in class `xyz`. 400 bytes is not that much of concern, but in my program I am passing an array which is taking one MB.

Comment: You may wanna see the article from Andrew Hunter about [Object Overhead: The Hidden .NET Memory Allocation Cost](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/object-overhead-the-hidden-.net-memory--allocation-cost/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The amount of memory that is needed to store a reference. As far as I remember, it is 8 bytes on a 32-bit machine and 12 bytes on a 64-bit machine.

Comment: Usually it's the size of a DWORD for 32-bit and the sizeof a QWORD (double-doubleword) for 64-bit. i.e 32-bits and 64-bits respectively.

Comment: Adding to @Alex's answer, Arrays are allocated on heap and passed by reference only.

Comment: Thanks you all for answering , i was aware of this but was not 100 % sure that's why gave trouble to you

Answer (score 1):

For reference types, only the reference itself is pushed onto the stack during a function call. For value types, the value itself is pushed onto the stack.

objects/arrays/etc are all reference types, which mean only a `reference` to the object is pushed onto the stack for a function call, the actual object itself will reside in the GC Heap or wherever the process is allocating dynamic memory. The size of a reference is architecture dependent, but will vary from 32-64 bits (4-8 bytes) on most modern systems.

You may want to read up on value and reference types:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx

This is one of the times where C# can be slightly counter-intuitive in its simplicity. It's easier to visualize from a C++ point of view:

```
double *data = new double[100]; //you can see here that "data" is merely a pointer to a double array with 100 elements, it doesn't actually hold the array itself.
somefunction(data); //now, it's more obvious what we're doing here: data is just a pointer, so all we're doing is passing a pointer to the function, not a double array.
```